# Stop Batch File from Beeping

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For some reason my batch script beeps when pressing Space at a PAUSE event.

I currently have both:

```
start /wait %comspec% /Q /C "net stop beep" >nul 2>&1
start /wait %comspec% /Q /C "sc stop beep" >nul 2>&1
```

...at the start of my script, which has successfully disabled the system beep, but now it has been replaced by a Windows "themed" beep.

Also this happens when I get to a CHOICE event and the user presses Space.

Any ideas on how to make a batch script completely silent, even during input "errors"?

Thanks,
D

Comment: Set the sound theme to _no sounds_ ?

Comment: Can I do that from the batch file temporarily? And just for the Windows beep?

The script is for automation across multiple machines, and would prefer to not have users just outright disable the sound theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your `choice` commands with something like this.

```
set /p choice="Please enter a choice: "
```

It'll require the user to hit enter but at least it won't beep.

If you really want to do it the hard way and turn off the default sound, I think you'll find it either in `HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\SystemAsterisk\.Current\(Default)` or in `HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\AppGPFault\.Current\(Default)`.

Here's a brief proof of concept.

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: stop bleeping service
start /wait %comspec% /Q /C "sc stop beep" >nul 2>&1

:: store current event setting for Asterisk
set loc=HKCU\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default\SystemAsterisk\.Current
for /f "tokens=3*" %%I in ('reg query %loc%') do (
    set asterisk=%%I %%J
)

:: choice with service stopped and Windows Asterisk sound event still active
choice

:: set Windows Asterisk event sound to ""
reg add "%loc%" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "" /f >NUL

:: choice with asterisk set to ""
choice

:: restore the sound
reg add "%loc%" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "%asterisk%" /f >NUL
```

If that doesn't work, try replacing `SystemAsterisk` with `AppGPFault`.  To be honest, I'm unable to recreate your symptom.  I hear silence after stopping the beep service.  So I'm not entirely sure which event is getting triggered when a user hits the space bar and the beep service is stopped.

Comment: Just as a side note, it's easier to use `reg /f` than piping `y`.

Comment: Thanks Bali C.  Good idea.  I modified the code to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Great idea! Will give it a try, turns out though that the beep that was happening was due to timing... the script was running too fast and was carrying the Space keypress from a previous pause event into the choice command. Adding a simple delay (ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 100 > nul) circumvents the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could always record a moment of silence, then use that to replace one of the Windows themed beeps.

I recommend that you post a little more of your code so we can see what is causing the beeps, because PAUSE should not do that.

Comment: Choice /N /C:APJ3CHQ /M "  >  Please press the appropriate key for your selection . . ."%1

Comment: Actually, I think that piping the output of Choice into `nul` might be better. But if memory serves, that doesn't usually work.